# Intutitive meaning behind the formal definition of sufficient statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, intuition, sufficient-statistics

According to the definition of sufficiency, a statistic is sufficient for a parameter if the conditional distribution of $X$ given a value of statistic does not depend upon the parameter.

What I am trying to understand is how does conditional distribution of $X$ not being a function of the parameter fit into the intuitive meaning of sufficiency i.e statistic value holding the same amount of information as that of the respective sample.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/84226/119261

Answer (score 1):

If the distribution of something you observe does not depend on a parameter, it cannot possibly give you information about it.

Now, if the distribution of $X$ depends on the parameter $\theta$ and the distribution of $X$ given the sufficient statistic $S$ does not, it must be the case that all information about $\theta$ is in $S$; once the value of $S$ is given, the value of $X$ becomes irrelevant, because the conditional distribution of $X$ no longer depends on $\theta$

Comment: Sir, I didn't get the part where you concluded that all the possible information about parameter is in S.Can you elaborate that part.

Answer (score 1):

We need some more notation. Suppose the random variable $X$ has a distribution from some family $f(x; \theta)$ parametrized by $\theta \in \Theta$. Suppose that $T=T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic (for $\theta$.) Then by the [factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem) we have 
$$
   f(x; \theta)= h(x) g(T(x); \theta)
$$
where $h$ is a function not depending on $\theta$. Now, using the result from [Can the Fisher factorization theorem be understood as a product of densities?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297652/can-the-fisher-factorization-theorem-be-understood-as-a-product-of-densities), this can be interpreted as a factorization of the distribution of $X$, and we can use this to simulate from the distribution of $X$ by first simulating $T$ and then simulating from the distribution of $X \mid T=t$.

So after having observed $T(x)=t$, we can simulate surrogate data having the same distribution as $X$ by simulating from the above conditional distribution, which by sufficency do not depend on  $\theta$. This is a way of giving intuitive meaning to sufficiency; knowing only $T(X)=t$ we can recreate by simulation surrogate data having the same distribution as $X$.

There are other ways to get intuitive meaning to *$T$ having the same information content as $X$*, via its use in inference. Without going into details

- The mle (maximum likelihood estimator) of $\theta$ is a function of $T$ (or if nonunique, can be chosen in such way)
- given a prior for $\theta$, the bayesian posterior will be a function of $T$

and there are many more general results of this sort. The two above should be easy exercises.